# Is it possible to recall old memories without altering them?

Tags: memory, plasticity

I want spend some time reminiscing about the past and I want to go deep. Upon Googling techniques on how to help memory recall I ran into an old fact I had forgotten about (ironically). The fact is that with every iteration of a memory reconstruction the memory is altered because it is open to suggestion. Of course tissues are plastic and they will change with time and use. I wanted to ask whether it is possible to do a recall in manner that conserves the integrity of the memory?

Comment: The answer is in your question isn't it?  *"With every iteration of a memory reconstruction the memory is altered because it is open to suggestion"*

Comment: No, not possible. Each time your retrieve the memory, you are also modifying it, including pairing it with the current affective state when you are recalling it.

Comment: I originally had may question as what way one can try to recall memories with minimal alteration of the original memory. I don't think there is any answer so I'll just leave this as is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can people improve their memory by training themselves to recall previously forgotten memories?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/15787/can-people-improve-their-memory-by-training-themselves-to-recall-previously-forg)

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question. I'm not sure anybody knows how to answer it.